# Bulleted RTF list gets indented differently on first line

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, rtf

I am using .NET and a Windows.Forms application.

In an RTF box I set (with `.Rtf =`) this RTF markup:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}          
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.14393}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs17 
{\pntext\f0 'B7\tab}{\*\pn\pnlvlblt\pnf0\pnindent0{\pntxta\'B7}}\fi-180\li260\f0 The first line in bullet list.
\par{\pntext\f0\'B7\tab}Second line.
\par{\pntext\f0\'B7\tab}Third line.
```

The visible result is like this:

```
⦁             The first line in bullet list.
⦁   Second line.
⦁   Third line.
```

There are a bunch of spaces inserted before the beginning of the text for the first line. I don't want that.

When I read back the RTF from the control, it is now:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset2 Symbol;}}

{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.14393}\viewkind4\uc1 

\pard{\pntext\f1\'B7\tab}{\*\pn\pnlvlblt\pnf1\pnindent0{\pntxtb\'B7}}\fi-180\li260\f0\fs24           \fs17 The first line in bullet list.\par

{\pntext\f1\'B7\tab}Second line.\par

{\pntext\f1\'B7\tab}Third line.\par

}
```

I have read resources like http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm and similar I and get the general ideas about RTF:

The format is supposed to degrade gracefully, so when doing newer stuff not supported by older readers, there is extra formatting of the older kind which the older reader can display to get a somewhat decent visual representation of the new formatting, while the older reader ignores tags it doesn't know about.

For lists, the first line sets up some kind of style which the following lines follow. I have tried tinkering with all the numerical constants in the formatting above, and I see how rendering gets shifted left or right depending on what I change, but the extra spaces remain.

Also weird, I think, that when I read back the RTF from the text control, there is an extra `\fs24` seemingly out of the blue.

It would also be helpful if any help or solution would preserve the *list* aspect and not just visually render a list. The reason is that the program later on converts the RTF to HTML, and it would be helpful if it knew to create `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags directly, and not just, for instance, bullet characters and new paragraphs.

Comment: There are list examples for RTF here on SO, but none of those works for me. Maybe they work better in Word, I don't know, but in the text control I can't get them to work.

Comment: Why did you tagged c# and vb.net? wich one are you using?

Comment: @Simo, this VS solution holds both languages, but to be perfectly honest, I was just fishing for more eyeballs potentially familiar with these issues.

Comment: Try using WordPad to to create a list and then inspect the saved file in a text editor.

Comment: @TnTinMn, good idea, looks promising so far.

Comment: @TnTinMn, thanks for "chatting" with me - I just needed a fellow human to get unstuck and look in new places. Getting a working minimal example (in this case from Wordpard) was exactly what I needed. It turned out that it worked perfectly - which led me to look closely at my original RTF formatting - it turns out that I had a *lot* of whitespace in a multi-line string in my VB code. This whitespace founds its way into the first paragraph. Removed it and, just like that, my list shows nicely.

Comment: You may have a limiting criterion that necessitates going through RTF on the journey to Html, but I would avoid doing so if at all possible.  Just in case you are not aware of it, you can use the WebBrowser control as an Html editor.  [Here is one such example.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winformsue/2006/03/29/using-the-webbrowser-control-as-a-powerful-dhtml-editor-in-windows-forms/)

Comment: @TnTinMn, OMG. Thanks! I thought I had a limiting criterion but maybe I don't. In any case, I will have to decide what to refactor out first. I think I will complete the current iteration with the RTF solution, then rip it out in the next. Depends on how well things go and how daring (reckless) I decide to act. :)

Answer (score 2):

`RichTextBox` has a `SelectionBullet` property which turns on bullets for selected text.

If you want to set bullets for selected text, you can use:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionBullet = true;
```

If you want to insert a bulleted text, you can use:

```
var i = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
var txt = "Lorem\nipsum\ndolor\n";
richTextBox1.SelectedText = txt;
richTextBox1.Select(i, txt.Length);
richTextBox1.SelectionBullet = true;
```